# Raspberry PI camera module

Tags: camera, video, driver, raspicam

This might seem like a strange question, but does anyone know the reason for the camera driver not be implemented as a SoC camera driver?

For those not familiar with this, it is a framework that uses V4L2 for cameras that use connections that aren't USB, PCI, etc. It seems that in this case this would be a perfect fit.

Comment: Hey Jamiro14 can I ask what is a SoC camera vs something else? I have posted a [question here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28943/why-raspberry-pi-camera-no-device-found-in-cheese-or-iceweasel) that might be related. Thanks

Comment: Hey @joelmaranhao I was refering to the SoC-Camera subsystem. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/video4linux/soc-camera.txt

Answer (score 1):

In what way is the bcm2835-v4l2 driver not an SoC camera driver?

i.e. this:

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=62364

Comment: Because it's only using the V4L2 API and not the Soc-Camera Subsystem (based on the V4L2 API)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

[UV4L](http://www.linux-projects.org) does have the `raspicam` V4L2 driver (and many other useful plug-in's)