# Why Raspberry Pi camera "no device found" in Cheese or IceWeasel?

Tags: raspbian, raspicam

I am testing the new Raspberry Pi 2 with its camera board.

I have setup my Pi2 with Raspbian.

I have connected the camera on the CSI port, enabled the camera module from `raspi-config`

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install cheese
```

I was able to test still and video features.

Now, how I'd like be able to check the cam on `cheese` or use it from my browser e.g. hangout, Firefox WebRTC ...

On Cheese the camera module is not found whereas a USB cam shows up? Same from a browser.

Why the RPi Cam module isn't found on Cheese or Browser? and can I fix it?

### UPDATE when using UV4L driver

Installed the UV4L driver, I can now select the camera board from the browser when I try to start a simple webrtc session *e.g. http://opentokrtc.com/testroom* However when I do share `Camera Board OV5647` I get a full screen snap (frozen), so I don't think it's getting a video stream from the cam, but that's already a great step forward.

*Please upvote the question if you find it legit and interesting*

Comment: have a look at the information here http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14 it will add a uv4l driver that will make the camera available to standard linux apps. I use it for motion.

Comment: hey Rob, I haven't tried yet but that looks promising. You should copy and paste your message into an "Answer" (rather than comment) so that I can accept it. Up vote my question if you found it is legit. Thanks mate

Answer (score 6):

The Raspberry Pi camera does not present itself out of the box as a standard uv4l device and as such generic Linux programs can not "see" the device.

There is a great third part tool available [UV4L](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14) that will create the necessary device nodes for standard media applications.

I use it with Motion very successfully. [My blog entry discussing it](http://jumpstation.co.uk/flog/Jul2014.html#p120720141944).

Comment: I followed your tips and I can now select the camera board from the browser when I try to start a simple webrtc session e.g. http://opentokrtc.com/testroom However when I do share "Camera Board OV5647" I get a full screen snap (frozen), so I don't think it's getting a video stream from the cam, but that's already a great step forward. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There's an officially supported v4l2 camera module for the RPI camera (*not* the same as UV4L). It needs to be loaded, so that may be your problem:

```
$ sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=62364

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what others said, `UV4L` also provides an HTTP WebServer module from which you can get the media stream (video + audio) via [WebRTC](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/news/article.php?storyid=174) too to your browser. At the moment audio seems to be work-in-progress.